# Async tasks not finishing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm trying to launch a lot of tasks, and have them execute only a part of their code, and then wait for a ManualResetEvent. After I start all the tasks I need, I Set the event, and they all execute.

I then need to know when they all executed, so I do a counter on how many started, inside the async functions. TasksStarted is increased when task starts, and TasksFinished, when it ends.

I have a while loop waiting for the tasks to execute, by checking TasksStarted==TasksFinished, and sometimes it goes into infinite loop, because TasksFinished goes to (for example) 8 and TasksStarted to 9.

Any idea why that's happening?

```
      private void SetNext(int x, int y)
    {
        if (Evaluate(x, y))
        {
            if(!IsAlive(x,y))
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Set(x, y);
                    });    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsAlive(x, y))
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Remove(x, y);
                });
            }
        }
    }

public async Task Remove(int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            tasksStarted++;
            Processing.WaitOne();
            if (!grid.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                tasksFinished++;
                return;
            }
            grid[x].Remove(y);
            tasksFinished++;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

public async Task Set(int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            tasksStarted++;
            Processing.WaitOne();
            if (!grid.ContainsKey(x))
            {
                grid.Add(x, new HashSet<int>());
            }
            grid[x].Add(y);
            tasksFinished++;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Those places you swallow exceptions without ever incrementing a counter *should* stand out to you... Also, this is what `Task.WaitAll()` is for.

Comment: I have breakpoints on the exception areas. They never throw an exception.

Comment: Take a look at this practical implementation of multitasking utilizing Task.WhenAll: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481643/dispatcher-in-wpf-apps-implementing-multiple-async-tasks. You may re-use it's core solution for your purpose.

Comment: Based on the little bit of code you posted here, this is almost certainly the exact same problem as in the marked duplicate: you aren't synchronizing access to the counter, so multiple threads incrementing the counter can leave the counter's final value less than it should be. If you believe you have a different problem, please post a new question and provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem so that it's possible to know for sure what your code is doing.